# How can I use Big Data to give results on an if-statement from data that is in two spreadsheets?

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to prove that a Big Data system like Apache Hadoop or Google BigQuery could be a better alternative to analyze and display a specific data faster and easier than building whole data models and display them from QlikView.

In this simple example I want to use a Big Data system to find out how high the rate of sales online are. Here for I want take the quote of sales and online sales from those two tables.

Sales:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vWuVvz7Sltf6gAys28Ayv6u9juFxZPKupRYTRkcQhTA/edit?usp=sharing

Online Sales:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/162Cosl_nn0iS1y4NpytVd8NsO7sj16NdmgjtA87ppIw/edit?usp=sharing

Could you guys please help me write a code for this to display the results when typing in the Customer Number? (Please check the spreadsheets)

So far I have Google BigQuery in my Google Cloud Platform and a Hadoop Cluster ready to be tested on. Depending on your knowledge, I might use either of each.

Unfortunately I have no code so far.

If I type for customer "1002" I want to get the result 44.4% as in the spreadsheets his Online Sales "2.000 €" divided by his Sales "4.500 €" equals 0.44.

Optional: If you have any idea how to display the data on Apache Ambari (or similar) I would highly appreciate to get your tutorial for this one too!

Thanks so much for your help!

[This is my frontend in BigQuery since 10.05.2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9AYj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution on BigQuery.

Firstly we need to get the data in the Google Sheets documents linked to BigQuery. You can do this by creating a table with the source as the Sheet in Google Drive, this is relatively simple to do through the UI:

[image: Google BigQuery Create Table Sheets Source]

You can define the schema and ignore the header row with the additional options.

[image: Google BigQuery Create Table Schema Options]

Once the tables have been setup we can then query them in BigQuery. The following SQL will give what you want on a per user basis. I have commented out a row where you could insert the Customer ID to only return that customer.

```
SELECT a.Customer AS Customer,
       round(100.00*sum(b.Online_Sales)/sum(a.Sales), 2) AS PctOnlineSales
FROM
    Dataset.Big_Data_Test_1_Sales a
JOIN
    Dataset.Big_Data_Test_1_Online_Sales b
ON a.Customer = b.Customer
--WHERE a.Customer IN ('1002')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Here are my results when running the above:

[image: Google BigQuery SQL Demo]

I assume in production you have some cases where users do not have purchases in both sheets. Switching to a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and making user of `IFNULL` & `ISNULL` functions would deal with issues associated with that.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you Eric! I get an error saying "Dataset was not found in location EU" when following your instructions. How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you able to share some screenshots of your environment? Perhaps the dataset/tables list and the query view. You can edit them into the original question.

Comment: Please check the screenshot I just added to my inquiry.

Comment: Did you change `Dataset.Big_Data_Test_1_Sales` to `Big_Data_Test_Spreadsheet.Big_Data_Test_1_Sales` to match your naming convention?

Comment: Let me know if there are any further issues.